# Outsystem tool Unattended Installation - Config Tool via Puppet

Tags: linux, windows, puppet, puppet-enterprise, outsystems

The outsystems manual installation, when clicking the Grant Permission on the Config Tool, it will prompt me to enter the type of authentication for connecting to the database, and the username / password. can we possible to handale with Puppet code.

We attempt to install the OutSystems tool using puppet code, but when we proceed, a pop-up window appears. Upon clicking on "grant permission," another window opens.